# Create adhoc network when disconnected from network

Tags: bash, networking, arch-linux

I am using ArchLinux and want to create an AdHoc network automatically when the connection to the home network drops (or the home network can't be connected to on startup). How can I achieve this?

I found this on the internet what would resolve the problem on startup but not when the network is disconnected from:

```
# RPi Network Conf Bootstrapper

createAdHocNetwork(){
    echo "Creating ad-hoc network"
    ifconfig wlan0 down
    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
    iwconfig wlan0 key aaaaa11111 #WEP key
    iwconfig wlan0 essid RPi      #SSID
    ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.200 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    /usr/sbin/dhcpd wlan0
    echo "Ad-hoc network created"
}

echo "================================="
echo "RPi Network Conf Bootstrapper 0.1"
echo "================================="
echo "Scanning for known WiFi networks"
ssids=( 'MyWlan' 'MyOtherWlan' )
connected=false
for ssid in "${ssids[@]}"
do
    if iwlist wlan0 scan | grep $ssid > /dev/null
    then
        echo "First WiFi in range has SSID:" $ssid
        echo "Starting supplicant for WPA/WPA2"
        wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf     > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "Obtaining IP from DHCP"
        if dhclient -1 wlan0
        then
            echo "Connected to WiFi"
            connected=true
            break
        else
            echo "DHCP server did not respond with an IP lease (DHCPOFFER)"
            wpa_cli terminate
            break
       fi
    else
        echo "Not in range, WiFi with SSID:" $ssid
    fi
done

if ! $connected; then
    createAdHocNetwork
fi

exit 0
```

`wicd` on the other side provides (pre/post)(dis)connect scripts but I have no idea for the startup

Comment: What networkmanager do you use? Wicd, netctl, any DE-specific?

Comment: I used Wicd. I Know there are (pre/post)(dis)connect scripts so I could use them to create an adhoc after an connection is dropped. But then I have no idea when it comes to the startup. Wicd normally tries to connect automatically to a known network but if it won't find any, how can then tell my computer to create an adhoc?
So I thought maybe there would be another solution for that without using wicd, netcf, etc. but instead configuring it with `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, etc. ...

Comment: Does nobody have an idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use wicd, maybe others (and sorry for "answer" :) ).
But a possible solution: if you run wicd-curses, try press 'O' (check README.curses: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wicd-devel/wicd/experimental/view/head:/curses/README.curses )

Comment: No problem ;) Yeah but that means I do it manually ...